# Does it make sense to still use repository pattern from EF 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Since the introduction of dependency injection in EF 6.0, does it still make sense to use Repository pattern? I thought the main use of repository pattern is to enable abstraction and testability. Now, they are accomplished using dependency injection. So, can we skip repository pattern and directly use context in the service layer?

Comment: You certainly can, and in fact you always could.  Whether it's a good choice or not seems really opinion-based to me.

Comment: DI is orthogonal to the Repository pattern ..

Comment: Abstraction and testability is not the only purpose of Repository pattern. For example, you can also implement caching within the repository. A real yes/no answer for your question depends on whether you use it only for testability purpose.

Comment: The improved testability of EF 6 is not based on the new service locator, but on `DbSet` methods and properties being virtual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx#virtual. Using repositories (on top of `DbSet`) has always been an option.